# Qué diferencia marca el role="button" en una etiqueta div

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

No entiendo el *role button* y que diferencia hay entre poner un *button* directamente?

```html
<div class="container" role="button"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

`role="button"` forma parte del conjunto de información conocido como [ARIA (Accessible Rich Internet Applications)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA). Son atributos que pretenden proporcionar información a los motores de accesibilidad sobre la función de los elementos HTML. O, lo que es lo mismo, facilitarles la comprensión de para qué sirve cada elemento.

Un `button` ya lleva implícito el atributo `role="button"`, por lo que no es necesario especificarlo en él. Si lo que se busca es un botón con aspecto de botón, lo más coherente es usar `button`.

No obstante, puede haber casos en que queremos emular el comportamiento de un botón, pero no queremos que tenga aspecto de botón. En ese caso, sería mejor emplear un div limpio y asignarle el `role="button"`. Así no heredará todo el CSS predeterminado de un `button` y resultará más fácil darle el diseño que queramos.